# Can't get object property in lightning component controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, javascript-controller

I am trying to access JS object properties in the client controller. I get undefined if I try access it by name. But I see the properties if I log the whole object. Something I am missing?

```
  var uploadedFiles = event.getParam("files");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(uploadedFiles));
    //var objectParsed = JSON.parse(uploadedFiles);
    var docId = uploadedFiles["name"];
    console.log(docId);
    for (var key in uploadedFiles) {
          if (uploadedFiles.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log(key);
          }
        }
```

Console output

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON `[{"name":"xxx","documentId":"xxx"}]` looks like an array, not an object.

Change the way you get the docId to

`var docId = uploadedFiles[0]["name"];` or `var docId = uploadedFiles[0].name;`

and the loop to

`for (var key in uploadedFiles[0]) {`

Comment: Thank you! SF Documentation says the event.getParam() returns a JS object, not an array. But that worked. Thanks again!

Comment: :) You never know... it pays to be eagle eyed when checking your debug logs. I've gone through this same thing too many times to count.